# List all the stored procedures which have no parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to find out which stored procedures in a database have no parameters. I tried these but I am not sure:

1) Joining tables `sys.all_parameters` and `sys.all_objects`:

```
select 
   ao.name,ao.type, ao.type_desc
from 
   sys.all_parameters pa
       left outer join 
   sys.all_objects ao
       on pa.object_id = ao.object_id
where 
    pa.name like ''
and 
    ao.type not in ('FN','AF','FS')
```

2) From table `information_schema.parameters`:

```
select * 
from
    information_schema.parameters 
where 
    parameter_mode not in ('in', 'out', 'inout')
```

3) From `information_schema.parameters`:

```
select * 
from
    information_schema.parameters 
where
    parameter_name like ''
```

However, I am not entirely sure if any of these are correct. Is there something a direct way?

Maybe something like:

```
select * from sys.procedures where xtype = 'P' and has_parameters=0
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
       name
FROM   sys.procedures pr
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                  FROM   sys.parameters p
                  WHERE  p.object_id = pr.object_id)
```